# Update part of webpage using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am using PHP to create my attendence websheet , when user enters in , he gets attendence for the current month . User can change the month using a drop-down , which refreshes the entire page . I want only the table to be refreshed not the entire page to reload .

Can anyone please tell me how to do this using PHP .

Comment: you can do this with ajax...

Comment: you can't. You need to use javascript and ajax calls.

Comment: Can u please tell me what changes need to be done to my php script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP runs server side. Very broadly this is what happens to a request coming from the user:

1. User clicks on drop-down option
2. Browser sends request for new page to server (myPage.php)
3. Server runs PHP code on myPage.php, resulting in some usually HTMl output (myPage.html*)
4. Server responds with myPage.html
5. Browser changes the page content to myPage.html

What you can do is use AJAX to send the request. What changes is that the browser gets the response back, but doesn't change the page content, it simply throws an event with the myPage.html content available to use however you want in JavaScript. On the PHP side, you can change nothing, the important part is the JavaScript that you have to write to update the page.

Obviously since you only change part of the page, it could be a good idea to not send the whole myPage.html back from the server and just send the section of the page that changes, or perhaps a blueprint on how to change the page.

*) myPage.html does not actually exist. It is strictly a name i gave to the output of the PHP script myPage.php.

You can find good resources on AJAX all over the web. I will give a link to one of the most reputable ones, but feel free to find one or more that suit you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

PS: Since you tagged the question as jQuery, you should know that jQuery has very good support for AJAX. I recommend you (learn to) use it.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Hey Tibos , thanx for u time , will certainly look into it

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **AJAX** for such things . Read about that .

Comment: Is it possible to use ajax code within my PHP or HTml script ....what changed need to be done then

Comment: Yes you can use with PHP.

Comment: if some ajax script is included in html file ... so what will be the extension of the file while saving ... i have html file and den a php file , html file has an option to take month and based on that month data from mysql is displayed vai PHP... now m using total page reload for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax to send http request on change event of dropdownlist to save it in database
  here is sample code to send request

```
  function makeattan(p)
  {

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","afilename.php,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax for this.

Build a function that will fetch the current page via ajax from the server. The data will then be put inside the same area in the page and replace old content with new one.

You can use jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

eg

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
    alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Note, load automatically replaces content.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX, by using both PHP and jQuery for example ; something like that :

HTML :

```
<a href="yourScript.php" class="ajaxLink">Load content</a>
<div id="dynamicContentDiv">

</div>
```

JS :

```
$( function() {
    $( ".ajaxLink" ).on( "click", function() {
        var ajaxUrl = $( this ).attr( "href" );
        $.get({
            ajaxUrl,
            function( response ) {
                $( "#dynamicContentDiv" ).html( response );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With this basic script, you send a GET request to your script, and put the response into `dynamicContentDiv` ; please refer to jQuery documentation, and AJAX resources for more advanced behavior. ;)